# Closed set via addition of two sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A =\{(x \in R^2 \mid \text{max}(|x|,|y|) \leq 1\}$ and $B = \{(0,y) \in R^2 \mid y \in R\}$. Show that the set $A + B = \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ is a closed subset of $R^2$.

Comment: Do you know what $A + B$ looks like well enough to draw a picture of it?

Comment: @pjs36 one is a square another is a st. line

Comment: And $A+B$, the one you're actually interested in?

Comment: @pjs36 is it an infinite rectangular strip?

Comment: Exactly! You should be able to show that $A + B = \{(x, y) : -1 \le x \le 1\}$, which I think is a better characterization; it should be straightforward to show that its complement is open.

Comment: Slightly more interesting would be to show that $A+B$ is closed when $B = \{(x,x) \mid x \in R\}$.